# Why does my audio buffer doesn't play any sound? [Web Audio API]

Tags: javascript, audio, buffer, web-audio-api

My audio buffer doesn't seems to work and I don't know why. I already tried opening it in Chrome and in Safari but nothing happens. I also checked that everything's ok with my audio file "Audio2.mp3".

```
"use strict"

//Create the Audio Context, compatible with older Firefox and Chrome browsers
function audioContextCheck(){
    if (typeof AudioContext !== "undefined"){
        return new AudioContext();
    }
    else if (typeof webkitAudioContext !== "undefined") {
        return new webkitAudioContext();
    }
    else if (typeof mozAudioContext !== "undefined") {
        return new mozAudioContext();
    }
    else {
        throw new Error('AudioContext not supported');
    }
}

var audioContext = audioContextCheck();


//Create audio buffer to the audio file with the XMLHttpRequest
var audioBuffer;

var getSound = new XMLHttpRequest();
getSound.open("get", "Audio2.mp3", true);
getSound.responseType = "arraybuffer";

getSound.onload = function(){
    audioContext.decodeAudioData(getSound.response, function(buffer) {
        audioBuffer = buffer;
    });
};

getSound.send();

//EventListener

window.addEventListener("load", playback);

//Now create the function necessary to play back the audio buffer

function playback(){
    var playSound = audioContext.createBufferSource();
    playSound.buffer = audioBuffer;
    playSound.connect(audioContext.destination);
    playSound.start(audioContext.currentTime);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, you trigger `playback()` before `audioBuffer` has been defined.

Try to wait until the audio xhr has fully loaded, assign the `audioBuffer` then perform the `playback()`, and it will work as expected.

E.g.

```js
//Create the Audio Context, compatible with older Firefox and Chrome browsers
function audioContextCheck() {
  if (typeof AudioContext !== "undefined") {
    return new AudioContext();
  } else if (typeof webkitAudioContext !== "undefined") {
    return new webkitAudioContext();
  } else if (typeof mozAudioContext !== "undefined") {
    return new mozAudioContext();
  } else {
    throw new Error('AudioContext not supported');
  }
}

var audioContext = audioContextCheck();


//Create audio buffer to the audio file with the XMLHttpRequest
var audioBuffer;

var getSound = new XMLHttpRequest();
getSound.open("get", "https://cdn.rawgit.com/devildrey33/devildrey33/ddb01d71/Ejemplos/BannerTest/Canciones/LevenRain_-_ActionMan_Versus_The_CyberParasites.mp3", true);
getSound.responseType = "arraybuffer";

getSound.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("xhrStatus").textContent = "Loaded";
  audioContext.decodeAudioData(getSound.response, function(buffer) {
    audioBuffer = buffer;
    playback(); // <--- Start the playback after `audioBuffer` is defined.
  });
};

getSound.send();

//EventListener

// window.addEventListener("load", playback);

//Now create the function necessary to play back the audio buffer

function playback() {
  var playSound = audioContext.createBufferSource();
  playSound.buffer = audioBuffer;
  playSound.connect(audioContext.destination);
  playSound.start(audioContext.currentTime);
}
```

```html
<p id="xhrStatus"> Loading the audio.. </p>
```

Comment: @IsaiasHerrera The sample above works though. Or probably the problem lies elsewhere such as audio permission in mobile browsers.

Comment: It worked! This was my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local

Comment: I like the song